# JPA add element to collection using CriteriaUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm on Hibernate (5.1) and I need to add an element to a collection field on all entities matching a criteria, without the need to fetch them all.

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public Date placedOn;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Item> items;

}
```

I need to add the same instance of a new `Item` to all `Order`s placed after a certain date. I need to use the Criteria API, not JPQL.

Is that possible? I can't find documentation on this.

P.S. The order/items case is just an example, I'm looking for a generalized method and I'll also need to adapt it to remove items from collections.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using CriteriaUpdate because it's not an update but many inserts because you have a ManyToMany relationship that relays on a relationship table in the database.

So you must query all Orders and then add the Item that will then generate the insert statements.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I know it's not a SQL `UPDATE`, but I thought JPA had some sort of JPQL `UPDATE Order o INSERT :item INTO o.items` and its relative Criteria method. Since in their underhood JPA implementations do these `INSERT`s when updating collection fields, I hoped they also provided means to let users do such operations programmatically…

Comment: No it cannot do that. Because you cannot do that either in one SQL statement.

Comment: JPA does no magic it just has another query language that at the end gets transformed to SQL

Comment: Thank you @simas_ch, I understand. Since I'll need to update collections in many entity classes very different one to the other, I'm trying to build an abstract `DAO<E>` with a `<X> addTo(String propertyName, X item)` method, but if JPA nor Hibernate provide an abstract way to do this, I'll have to take the reflection path (hoping it works with proxied entity updates).

Comment: I would do this using SQL as it would be much faster. You would not need to read all the Orders just to add an Item.

Comment: I can't use SQL, since I won't know table/column real names (and I don't want to inspect join annotations, follow `mappedBy`s and so on).

Comment: I see. IMHO it's not possible to create a fast database application with only using JPA. SQL in many places is faster.